# Removing duplicated from sorted list (OCaml)

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to remove duplicate items from already sorted list in OCaml. This is my code:

```
let rec remove_dup = function
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: [] -> hd :: []
    | hd :: hd2 :: tl -> if (hd == hd2) (remove_dup tl) :: hd else (remove_dup (h2 :: tl) :: hd;;
```

I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Another side comment: `hd::[]` can be written `[hd]` for extra legibility. :)

Answer (score 3):

The OCaml `if` looks like `if` *expr1* `then` *expr2* `else` *expr3*. You're missing the keyword `then`.

You also have unbalanced parentheses. It looks like you need a right parenthesis at the very end.

After these fixes you have some type errors that you should look at.

As a side comment, don't use `==` to test for equality. It's a special-purpose operator for advanced uses. The day-to-day equality operator is `=`.